# How to conditionally subset a list using the purrr package

Tags: r, list, subset, purrr

I have the following list:

```
x <- list(1:5, 1:10)
x
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5

#> [[2]]
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

and would like to select only the elements which contain 10.

Desired result:

```
#> [[1]]
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

How can I do this concisely and in a *single* line using the pipe operator and the purrr package?

The foll. code works, but feels a little clumsy.

```
x %>% map_lgl(~contains(.,10L)) %>% subset(x,.)
```

Is there a better way using `x` and the pipe operator each just once?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`purrr::keep`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/keep.html)

```r
library(purrr)

x <- list(1:5, 1:10)

x

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

x %>% keep(~ 10 %in% .x)

#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: this is purrr...fect ! :-) I'm new to purrr and somehow missed this function. many thanks @austensen

Answer (score 2):

```
x[sapply(x, function(x) any(x == 10))]
```

Comment: `x[sapply(x, is.element, el=10)]` if you're looking to squeeze a few characters out of it.

Comment: thanks @HongOoi, but was looking for a way using the pipe operator and purrr.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) 10 %in% x, x)
#[[1]]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

Or with `purrr`

```
x %>%
    purrr::map_lgl(~10 %in% .)  %>%
    x[.]
```

We can make this a function

```
filterL <- function(lst, val){
      lst %>%
         purrr::map_lgl(~val %in% .) %>%
        lst[.]
 }

filterL(x, 10)
#[[1]]
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: thanks @akrun, but the [purrr::keep](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/keep.html) function in the accepted answer is what I was looking for.